# jags: coda package, how to select multiple parameters

Tags: r, jags

I used `r2jags` to run jags and do the sampling. Then, I used `coda` package to check convergence. As I have many subjects and many parameters, I would need to manually type them as the codes below. Are there any easier approaches that I can for example, choose `gamma` for every subject? Or, just select `gamma` from subject 1 to 10 without typing them manually?

```
codaSamples = as.mcmc.list(samples$BUGSoutput)

acfplot(codaSamples[,c('gamma[1]','gamma[2]','gamma[3]','gamma[4]','gamma[5]','gamma[6]',
                         'gamma[7]','gamma[8]','gamma[9]','gamma[10]','gamma[11]','gamma[12]',
                         'gamma[13]','gamma[14]','gamma[15]')],lag.max=1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reproducible example would be nice but presumably

```r
cols <- sprintf("gamma[%d]",1:15); codaSamples[,cols]
```

would do what you need? Or

```r
cols <- grep("^gamma",colnames(codaSamples)); codaSamples[,cols]
```

Comment: Sorry, I just tried your methods. By using `sprintf`, cols will not be a mcmc list so I can't put it into `acfplot` function.

Comment: Are there any approaches I can make the data as mcmc list so able to use the functions in the `coda` pacakge?

Comment: `cols` is not supposed to be an MCMC list; `codaSamples[,cols]` is. If you want more clarification can we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: Really sorry, I had some misunderstanding about the codes. I understand how it works now. Thank you very much for your helps!!